# Litle-$o_p$ notation question

Tags: notation, asymptotics

Suppose that $f_n/f = 1-o_p(1)$. Is this equivalent to saying $f_n/f \overset{p}{\to} 1$? Or is one weaker than the other?

Comment: What is $\overset {p} \to$

Comment: convergence in probability

Comment: I think they are equivalent.